# How to insert an attachment to a System.Net.Mail.mailMessage by using Body properties

Tags: c#

I need to send email with attachment. No problem if I do it by myself, but...

Inside the company I work for, I need to pass through a web service awaiting an email and a body.

I know that the implementation of this service use System.Web.mail.Mailmessage doing probably something like this:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
mm.to = email_;
mm.body = body_;
...
```

So, is there a way to create a string that'll contain my attachement so I can send it to the web service ?

thx.

--Edition--
I must use a class "TheCompanyMail" that has 2 properties (to,body) and one method (send). This class is a proxy to a webservice. This webservice is the one that really sends the mail. 
The problem is that I need to add an attachement to the mail and really don't know how to do it.

Example

```
File f = MyFuturAttachementFile;

TheComapyMail m = new TheCompanyMail();
m.to = "myCustomer@Company.com"
m.body = "Here is the file you're waiting for:"+f.ToString(); //this of course doesn't work !!!
m.send();
```

So I'm wondering if I can format the string of the body property to add attachement ?

Comment: I dont understand your problem.

Comment: To be more clear.

If i should do it by myself, i would use the property attachement of MailMessage and everything would be fine.

But, I'm forced to use a web service that has only 2 params: email + body.

So, i need to format the body string to insert the attachement inside before calling the webservice and I realy don't known how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm right, but in my opinion there is no way to pass attachments by adding them in a string to message body. The main why-not argument is safety. I don't think that Microsoft could allow this class to behave like this...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way, you need to add it to the `Attachements` property of the `MailMessage`.

Why don't you store the file somewhere else where they can access it and just send them a link to it instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Html email where the "attachment" is actually link to download the file rather than an actual email attachement.